# Self Reference A Table - Compress To One Row - Calculate Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a SQL Server 2012 query that will turn a table like below into the desired output below.

The denominator and the numerator are provided in the T1 row.  T2 and T3 values are provided on separate rows.  Value needs to be calculated with those two values (T2 and T3).

```
Table               
Identifier        Tdate           Denominator   Numerator   Value
T1                05/01/2014      T2            T3  
T2                05/01/2014                                50
T3                05/01/2014                                5
T1                06/01/2014      T2            T3  
T2                06/01/2014                                80
T3                06/01/2014                                4
```

Desired output:

```
Identifier  Tdate       Denominator Numerator   Value   DenNum  NumNum
T1          05/01/2014  T2          T3          0.100   50      5
T1          06/01/2014  T2          T3          0.050   80      4
```

I have tried many things, but with no success.  Below is the latest just to show what I've done, but do not consider this to be an elegant solution.  It is obviously incomplete.

```
SELECT  E.Identifier,
        E.Denominator, 
        E.Numerator, 
        M.Identifier, 
        M.Denominator, 
        M.Numerator, 
        E.Value, 
        M.Value 
FROM    Table   E, 
        Table   M
WHERE   (E.Identifier = M.Denominator OR E.Identifier = M.Numerator)
AND     E.Tdate in ('05/01/2014')
AND     M.Tdate in ('05/01/2014');
```

Comment: is that your table? or the result of a query?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: The "Table" is the actual table.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a self-join does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       tn.value / td.value, td.value as dennum, tn.value as numnum 
from t join
     t td
     on t.denominator = td.identifier and t.tdate = td.tdate join
     t tn
     on t.numerator = tn.identifier and t.tdate = tn.tdate
where t.identifier = 'T1';
```

Note:  if `value` is an integer, then use `tn.value * 1.0 / td.value`.  SQL Server does integer division.

Comment: you should also include `TDate` in the `join` conditions.

Comment: When I run this, I get the error message

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 't'.

Comment: @GBOHNC . . . `t` is for your table name.